# Does the UniqueId you get from Android change sometime?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-10.0

After reading a lot and documenting it is clear to me that Android 10 cannot get the IMEI anymore.

I used it (IMEI) to determine which user had which phone in possession and thus carried out a validation in the Login so that the user would not start on a phone that was not his assigned, now as I read an option is to use the UniqueID, or I don't know what others There will be options, but how much do these Ids change? with each OS update? a new big version of android? or do they never change?

My actual code:

```
 if (IMEIValue == null)
        IMEIValue = getUniqueID();
```

Please any example with code.

thanks!

Comment: Reminder: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static String uniqueID = null;
private static final String PREF_UNIQUE_ID = "PREF_UNIQUE_ID";
public synchronized static String id(Context context) {
   if (uniqueID == null) {
      SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
         PREF_UNIQUE_ID, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      uniqueID = sharedPrefs.getString(PREF_UNIQUE_ID, null);
      if (uniqueID == null) {
         uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
         Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
         editor.putString(PREF_UNIQUE_ID, uniqueID);
         editor.commit();
      }
   }
    return uniqueID;
}
```

> UUID.randomUUID() method generates an unique identifier for a specific installation. You have just to store that value and your user will be identified at the next launch of your application.

https://medium.com/@ssaurel/how-to-retrieve-an-unique-id-to-identify-android-devices-6f99fd5369eb

p.s. Hope I could answer your question or at least gave a hint somehow :)

Comment: @Berroterán you are welcome. If it helped, plz do not forget to upvote :)